# How to intercept SSH Password request in a Java Program

Tags: java, ssh, passwords, tty

I am need to spawn a SSH connection from a JAVA program using ProcessBuilder and a USERID/PASSWORD combination.

I have already successfully implemented SSH connections using Ganymed, JSch, a combination of JAVA Processbuilder and Expect scripting (Expect4J also), JAVA ProcessBuilder and SSHPASS script and SSH Shared Key.

Security is NOT a concern at this point in time and all I am after is to be able to support programmatically all kinds of combinations for SSH connection.

My problem is the Password prompt that SSH throws somewhere that is not on STDIN/STDOUT (on a tty I believe). This is my last hurdle to overcome.

My question is there a way to intercept SSH password request and provide it from my JAVA code?

Please, note this is a very narrow question (and all the above information was to guarantee the answer would not be too broad).

Here is a sample code of what I am trying:

```
import  java.io.*;
import  java.util.*;

public class ProcessBuilderTest {
    public  static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
                                "/usr/bin/ssh",
                                "nyuser@myserver.com",
                                "export NOME='Jennifer Lawrence'; echo $NOME"
                                );


        pb.redirectErrorStream(); //redirect stderr to stdout
        Process process = pb.start();
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        process.waitFor();
     }
}
```

But, when I run it I got this:

```
[memphis BuilderTest]# java ProcessBuilderTest

myuser@myserver's password:
```

and after I type the password, I got the rest of the output:

```
Jennifer Lawrence

[memphis BuilderTest]#
```

Again, the specific question is:
Is there a way to spawn an external ssh client (OpenSSH, Tectia SSH, SecureCRT, etc) using PasswordAuthentication method (no other method can be used) process using JAVA ProcessBuilder interface (no other language can be used), intercept/capture the password prompt and respond/interact providing that password from my JAVA code (so the user does not need to type it)?

Comment: Why are you implementing it in so many different ways?!

Comment: My team at work create JAVA based tools to be used by the infrastructure teams and each team has its own way of doing things (it is a worldwide corporation) and we cannot limit things by forcing a standard or pattern.

Comment: Well there is a reason why the password prompt is done in a way that cannot be intercepted. The reason is that hard coded passwords in programs or scripts are undesirable, to say the least.

Comment: @Ingo, I agree that passwords MUST not be hard coded anywhere, and that is NOT what we do, one example I can give you is that some of our users (operators) enter their password at the beginning of a session that may spawn through many servers and our system keeps that information encrypted in memory, and uses it when its needed but, like I said some of the operations will be carried/executed in servers in many different countries, subjected to many different regulations and maintained by many different support groups .... so standards are almost impossible to enforce.

Comment: @Capoeira_us I understand your problem, but consider what would happen if you actually could intercept the password prompt and answer it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn about pseudo-ttys, assuming that you are operating on Linux. The password prompt is on the tty device. You will need to build a separate process running against a pseudo-tty instead of just inheriting your tty device, and then you can intercept the password prompt.

This is a moderately complex process.

There is a library that supports some of this: http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/FAQ.html. You might find reading its source illuminating if it is available.

Comment: That is what I was thinking too, my problems in this case are:
1. How to allocate a pty in JAVA (even worse on both Linux and Windows) 
2. how to fire the ssh client against that pty allocation.
I have searched the iNet l;ooking for this answer (some sample code for instance) and all Iǘe seen is quite a ew people asking this very same questions. :(

Comment: Windows does not have 'pty's in the same sense, I have no advice to offer for Windows.

Comment: First of all Thank you for the reply. Ganymed is one of the pure JAVA SSH implementations that I am using in my code so I am going to take a look at its source.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? From looking at JPty and others, it isn't trivial to create a pseudo-tty in a platform independent way or with something that doesn't involve native JNI calls. I have a similar issue in that I wish to automate logging into an SSH host and I am unable to capture the password prompt. My program prompts the user for their password, so it isn't stored in code, but is entered multiple times.

Comment: You realize how long ago I wrote this. I no longer work at the place where I did this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

While it has been suggested that a pseudo-tty (pty) is required to simulate a terminal, the accepted answer doesn't provide a working solution - there are also lots of similar questions with no working answers.

Here are two solutions that allow you to capture the "Password:" prompt in SSH and enter the password in an automated way without using SSH_ASKPASS or Expect.

Why use one programming language when you can use two - the first option isn't ideal, but it demonstrates the solution:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/python", "-c", "import pty; pty.spawn(['/usr/bin/ssh', '<hostname>'])");
```

The above example makes use of the Python `pty` module to wrap SSH into a PTY. Although it is simple, it doesn't provide any flexibility to allow you to modify any terminal properties like the passed window size.

The other more lightweight option is to use a PTY wrapper in C - the `pty` tool from the "Advanced Programming in the UNIX® Environment" book is just this - the source can be found at https://github.com/abligh/pty.

You will then use it in a similar way, but referencing the `pty` tool instead of Python:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/pty", "/usr/bin/ssh", "<hostname>");
```

This is the same approach that Expect uses to simulate a PTY, which is why you are able to intercept it using Expect. It goes without saying that tunneled clear text passwords are insecure and public key authentication should always be the preferred way of doing this.